# How to import a table from Oracle to Hive using sqoop in java?

Tags: java, oracle, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I'm having hard time figuring out all the required parameters as the documentation is lacking and I cannot seem to find a working JAVA code sample which does that.

Note: The question does NOT refer to sqoop 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sqoop 1 do not have official JAVA API and thus there is no official documentation how to do it. We've seen a lot of people requesting for such API and thus we've added it in Sqoop 2. You could potentially use class Sqoop and enter all parameters you would set up on the command line, however please note that such usage is not supported and you might hit many issues with such approach.

Comment: Thank you for this information.  
Do you know where I can download the latest PRODUCTION version jar of sqoop 2 and are there any JAVA code examples to do import from oracle to hive using sqoop 2?